# AWS Lambda RDS Proxy - Not able to select RDS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, proxy, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-proxy

I am not able to select any RDS instance from my lambda to setup a database proxy.

I already created 3 different types (mysql, mariadb, aurora) and it never shows me a RDS instance to select.

What do I have to do to be able to select a RDS Instance to create a proxy from Lambda?

> SOLVED
>
> **The problem was that I was not using MySQL 5.6 or 5.7 version. It ONLY
> works with that versions**.

Now my problem is timeout.

Comment: I just came across this problem, do you know if they will support version 8? also where did u find the information that it only supports 5.6 and 5.7

Comment: @Kay https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-proxy.html#rds-proxy.limitations